# Javascript Modules are not working with live server

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, module

I am using live server and everything works fine if I use one js file. but when I use modules, it gives error in console. due to some reason it doesnt access other javascript file. I am using script properly and it works, and when using module, i define type="module" and its defer also but wont work.

GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/dusra net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

thats the error in console, and 'dusra' is module

I tried live server extention, live server node version. everything, but it just doesnt work with modeuls only, normally live reload works fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and then realized I forgot to add ".js" to the imported file name.
What I had was import {function} from "./data" when instead I should have done
**import {function} from "./data.js"**
Try this and see if it works.